# AngularJs hide all alerts: Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: angularjs, alert

I have an angularJS component that displays alerts when something goes wrong while submitting, these alerts are not auto dismissed by design.

But, when the user fix all errors (there can be many alerts displayed on the screen) and submit I want to dismiss these alerts.

Based on this example https://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/j46Yh/
I did something like this:

```
(function(){    
var mainApp = angular.module("myApp");

function AlertsCtrl($scope, alertsManager) {
    $scope.alerts = alertsManager.alerts;
}

mainApp.factory('alertsManager', function() {
return {
    alerts: {},
    addAlert: function(message, type) {
        this.alerts[type] = this.alerts[type] || [];
        this.alerts[type].push(message);
    },
    clearAlerts: function() {
        for(var x in this.alerts) {
           delete this.alerts[x];
        }
    }
};

mainApp.controller("addUserCtrl", ['Restangular', 'alertsManager', '$alert', 'roles', '$window' , function(Restangular, alertsManager, $alert, roles, $window) {
    var that = this;
    init();

    that.submit = function() {
        var data = {
            user : that.name,
            role : that.role.serverName,
            credentials : that.password1
        }
        Restangular.all("admin").all("user").all("add").post(data).then(function() {
            //$alert({title: 'Add User:', content: 'Completed succefully', type: 'success', container: '#alert', duration: 5, show: true});
            alertsManager.addAlert('Completed succefully', 'alert-success');
            init();
            alertsManager.clearAlerts();
        }, function(reason) {
            //$alerts{title: 'Add User:', content: reason.data.error, type: 'danger', container: '#alert', show: true});
            alertsManager.addAlert(reason.data.error, 'alert-error');
        });
    }

    function init() {
        that.name = "";
        that.roles = roles;
        that.role = that.roles[0];
        that.password1 = "";
        that.password2 = "";
    }
}]);
})();
```

HTML:

```html
<div ng-controller="addUserCtrl as ctrl">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="ctrl.submit()">
      <div class="panel-heading">Add User</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">User Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="ctrl.name"></input>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="role" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Role: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
         <select class="form-control" id="role" ng-model="ctrl.role" ng-options="opt.displayName for opt in ctrl.roles"></select>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" ng-model="ctrl.password1"></input>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Re-enter Password: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8" ng-class="{'has-error' : ctrl.password1 != ctrl.password2}">
         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" ng-model="ctrl.password2"></input>
         <p class="help-block" ng-if="ctrl.password1 != ctrl.password2">Passwords don't match</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="!ctrl.name || !ctrl.password1 || !ctrl.password2 || ctrl.password1 != ctrl.password2">OK</button>
      </div>
      
      <div ng-controller="AlertsCtrl">
          <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in alerts" class="alert {{key}}">
              <div ng-repeat="msg in val">{{msg}}</div>
          </div>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But I'm getting:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
angular.js:14747 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=addUserCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not complete all brackets correctly.

Below should be like this:

```
mainApp.factory('alertsManager', function() {
  return {
    alerts: {},
      addAlert: function(message, type) {
        this.alerts[type] = this.alerts[type] || [];
        this.alerts[type].push(message);
      },
      clearAlerts: function() {
        for(var x in this.alerts) {
          delete this.alerts[x];
        }
      }
  }
});
```

You forgot to complete the factory by `});`.

And that is why indentation is so important.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Yes was silly, but I copied as is from that example.

Comment: I still have one issue that alerts are not shown on the screen!
I added the html to my post as well.
It's not reaching this code:
function AlertsCtrl($scope, alertsManager) {
     $scope.alerts = alertsManager.alerts;
 };

Comment: angular.js:14747 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=AlertsCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: You can not define `AlertsCtrl` in function style. Define same as `addUserCtrl`

Comment: Or define all controller in function style.